# Ack syntax for a file containing foo and bar

Tags: ack

What's the ack syntax to find all files containing foo and also bar?

Comment: Given that `ack` is (almost) a drop-in replacement for `grep`, the answers in [How to search files where two different words exist?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67794/how-to-search-files-where-two-different-words-exist) should work here too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First we need to select the files that contain `foo` and, from that list of files, selects files that also contain `bar`.  Thus:

```
ack -l foo | ack -x bar
```

As you can see, this works in two steps:

1. `ack -l foo` produces a list of the names of files that contain `foo`.
2. `ack -x bar` searches the files named on stdin for the expression `bar`.

Comment: Shouldn't that first bit be `ack -l foo *` ?

Comment: @roaima  If no files or directories are given on the command line, `ack` defaults to searching recursively starting with the current directory.  This default is similar to `grep -r pattern`.  Your approach. of course, would work also.

Comment: Thank you. It's a new command to me, but the man page seemed to jump on the "it's a drop-in for `grep`" line. (I'll delete this later. Or maybe you can.)

Comment: @roaima Yes, it is similar but different.  To make it more like `grep`, I have a `~/.ackrc` file that contains `--no-recurse`.   (I can, of course, override that on the command line with `ack -r`.)