# Find text files that have 2 terms in them (in any order, at any line)

Tags: awk, sed, grep, find

I have been looking at `grep -e` where you are doing an "and" operation which is the sort of thing I want.  However, if I get it right, the two terms have to be in the same line to be returned.

What I am interested instead is find me all documents in a directory that have both terms, possibly on different lines.  If order matters, I do know that one term will always occur before the other, however certainly a general purpose solution would be just fine.

Comment: Perhaps https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/67794/117549 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL&DR

**Note**: You have to test which one is the fastest for yourself.

```
grep -rlzE '(TermOne.*TermTwo)|(TermTwo.*TermOne)'

find . -type f -exec grep -q 'TermOne' {} \; \
               -exec grep -q 'TermTwo' {} \; \
               -print

awk '/TermOne/{if(p==0)p=1; if(p==2)p=3}
     /TermTwo/{if(p==0)p=2; if(p==1)p=3}
     p==3{print FILENAME;p=0;nextfile}' ./*
```

## One File

There is no way to build a regex that could match two separate strings in a file.

It is possible to search for two terms with either alternation:

```
grep -E '(TermOne.*TermTwo)|(TermTwo.*TermOne)' file
```

or lookahead:

```
grep -P '(?=.*TermOne)(?=.*TermTwo)' file
```

but only if the two terms are **on the same line**

It is also possible to make the whole file act as one file (if the file doesn't contain NULs. Unix text files don't) with the GNU grep `-z` option:

```
grep -zE '(TermOne.*TermTwo)|(TermTwo.*TermOne)' file
```

It is not possible to use `-z` with `-P` at the same time, so, no lookahead solutions possible as of today.

The other alternative is to grep twice:

```
<file grep 'TermOne' | grep -q 'TermTwo'
```

The exit code of the whole pipe will signal `0` only if both terms were found in one file.

Or, to use awk:

```
awk '/TermOne/{if(p==0)p=1; if(p==2)p=3}
     /TermTwo/{if(p==0)p=2; if(p==1)p=3}
     p==3{print "both terms found"; exit}' file
```

## list files

The first two solutions from above will work to recursively list all files by adding the options `-r` (recursive, which then there is no need for a filename) and `-l` (list matching filenames).

```
grep -rlzE '(TermOne.*TermTwo)|(TermTwo.*TermOne)'
```

Or, using find (two grep calls):

```
find . -type f -exec grep -q 'TermOne' {} \; -exec grep -q 'TermTwo' {} \; -print
```

Or, using awk (the glob will include only the PWD):

```
awk '/TermOne/{if(p==0)p=1; if(p==2)p=3}
     /TermTwo/{if(p==0)p=2; if(p==1)p=3}
     p==3{print FILENAME;p=0;nextfile}' ./*
```

Comment: I had tried the grep -E method, that was what I was trying to work with, but somehow I did not get it 100% right I guess.  With the options and form above, I am seeing the correct number or results come back now.  That is the solution I will go with as I have 2 terms (not more) in each file.