# find + grep to Search for Files Containing Multiple Strings

Tags: grep, find

I have the following being sent to my command line:

```
find /base/dir1 /base/dir2 -type f -exec /x/y/z/grep -e lolol -e wow {} +
```

This returns each file containing one or both of the supplied strings (`lolol` and `wow`). What I would like to do is to only return the files that contain both strings (AND not OR). If possible how could I accomplish this?

EDIT: The searched strings would need to be present in each file returned but not necessarily on the same line.

EDIT 2: I do not have the -r or -R options

Comment: @StephenKitt I am fairly new to this so I will have to research the solution found in your link some. If this does in fact offer a viable solution to search for a string1 AND a string2 it should suffice but again I will need to see if all mentioned is available on my OS

Comment: `find . -type f -exec grep -q FIND {} \; -exec grep -l ME {} \;` from [the accepted answer to the question I linked above](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/67820/86440) will work with any POSIX-compliant implementation of `find` and `grep`.

Comment: @StephenKitt I have tested that and it does seem to answer my question, thank you for the response. I can delete this post or accept as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps use GNU awk instead of grep:

```bsh
find /base/dir1 /base/dir2 -type f -exec gawk '
    FNR == 1 {p1 = p2 = 0}
    /lolol/  {p1 = 1} 
    /wow/    {p2 = 1}
    p1 && p2 {print FILENAME; nextfile}
' {} +
```

Comment: I have found my solution in a previous post but I will explore this as an option. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't find a way of doing that using the same `find`, so I tried comparing the results of both greps, here's what I came up to:

```
comm -12 <(find . -type f -exec grep -l lolol {} + | sort) <(find . -type f -exec grep -l wow {} + | sort)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Made some changes, I hope it serves your use case!